# How to forward all unknown parameters in constructor to initialize the member object?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing

I am trying to do something like this:

```
struct Foo {
    int _val;
    Foo(int v) : _val(v){} 
};

struct Bar {
    const std::string &_name;
    Bar(const std::string &name) : _name(name) {} 
};

template<typename T>
struct Universal {
    T _t;
    Universal(...) : _t(...) {} 
};

// I want to use Universal for Foo abd Bar in the same way:
Universal<Foo> UF(9);       // 9 is for Foo
Universal<Bar> UB("hello"); // "hello" is for bar
```

In the code above, I would like to forward all parameters in Universal's constructor to T's constructor.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 5):

You need to make `Universal` constructor be a variadic template, and use a parameter pack and perfect forwarding.

```
template<typename T>
struct Universal {
    T _t;

    template <typename... Args>
    Universal(Args&&... args) : _t(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {} 
};
```

Unfortunately as AndyG notes in the comments, this means that if you try and copy a non-const `Universal` object, the forwarding version gets preferred - so you need explicit const and non-const copy constructors!

```
template<typename T>
struct Universal {
    T _t;

    template <typename... Args>
    Universal(Args&&... args) : _t(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {} 

    Universal(const Universal& rhs): _t(rhs._t) {}
    Universal(      Universal& rhs): _r(rhs._t) {}

    // ... but not move constructors.
};
```

or use the SFINAE approach shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39646176/771073), to make sure the default constructor is preferred.

Comment: Yep, but one gotcha here is that this constructor will be preferred over the copy and move constructors most of the time. Extra work would need to be done if you intend otherwise.

Comment: @AndyG are you sure about that? Won't a variadic template ctor be a less match than a cpy ctor?

Comment: @bolov: The problem is that most of the time when people want the copy ctor called, the argument they pass in isn't already const, so the forwarding reference is a better match.

Comment: @AndyG Jesus, the ways C++ can bite you in the a**.

Comment: Are you sure:  I thought a template was *never* a copy constructor.

Comment: [Here's an example of what I mean](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5942bf263ec506b)

Comment: I should also add that I was wrong about the move ctor, this is really only a problem for the copy ctor.

Comment: @AndyG That is because it is an exact match in that case which is preferred over the template always.

Comment: OK.  You're sure.  Eeeew!

Comment: @MartinBonner This is why SFINAE should be applied to template constructors.  Here is a useful Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645986/constructor-using-stdforward

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
template<typename T>
struct Universal {
    T _t;
    Universal(const T& val) : _t(val) {} 
};
```

iff performance is of concern or if you want to support move only types you can forward the parameter:

```
template<typename T>
struct Universal {
    T _t;
    template <class U>
    Universal(U&& val) : _t(std::forward<U>(val)) {} 
};
```

Please note we need a template parameter `U` for the ctor in order for the forwarding to work. `T&&` would be just a rvalue reference.

If you want to get more fancy, you can construct in place:

```
template<typename T>
struct Universal {
    T _t;
    template <class... Args>
    Universal(Args&&... args) : _t(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {} 
};
```

As [AndyG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27678/andyg) suggested in a comment, extra work would need to be done if you want cpy and mv ctors to work as expected.

The rule is: keep it simple unless there is a good reason justifying the complications. I think that the first variant is more than enough for you.

Comment: If Foo or Bar have an explicit constructor, or don't have a copy constructor, then you will have to forward the parameter, whether or not you care about performance.

Comment: the explicit ctor is not a problem. You are right about move-only types. Ty, good catch

Comment: I think the explicit ctor is a problem:  `struct Foo{ explicit Foo(int i) {} }; void f(const Foo& f) {}; f(1);` will fail because you are trying to implicitly create a Foo.  That is what you are suggesting in your first suggestion.

Comment: @MartinBonner if the constructor is explicit, then the expected way would be `f(Foo{1})`.  That's why it's explicit.

Comment: similar, I would want `universal<Foo>` to work like this: `f(universal<Foo>){}; f(Foo{1})`, which it does.