# Using std::move() vs. assign in constructor member initializer list

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, initialization, move-semantics

What is the advantage of using std::move() in parametrized constructor (with initializer list) instead of regular member initialization, i.e., assign?

e.g.,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename V>
class myVec{
    private:
        std::vector< std::vector<V> > vec;

    public:
        myVec1(const std::vector< std::vector<V> > &myArr):vec(myArr) {};
        myVec2(const std::vector< std::vector<V> > &myArr):vec(std::move(myArr)) {};
        };
```

How much of an advantage (memory, performance, etc.) does one gain from using myVec1 instead of the other?

Comment: You will normally see this when the argument is passed by value (or r-value reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No performance difference in this case.

`std::move(myArr)` will produce a const rvalue reference to myArr. Now since myArr is not modifiable binding this to an rvalue reference is invalid, but it can bind to a const lvalue reference. Thus `vec(std::move(myArr))` will ultimately call the copy constructor of `vector`.

What you want here is:

```
myVec(const std::vector< std::vector<V> > &myArr):vec(myArr) {}; // 1
myVec(std::vector< std::vector<V> > &&myArr):vec(std::move(myArr)) {}; // 2
```

Now coming back onto your original question, say you have the constructors as above. If you're using move-ctor(2), you're obviously saving on a lot of copy. Do note that here you're `moving` the ownership of the data from the original vector, so keep in mind your use-case.

> How much of an advantage

I'll just say a LOT.

Comment: With your forwarding constructor design, `std::is_constructible<myVec<int>, std::string>` is `true_type`, even though you can't construct a `myVec<int>` from a `string`.  Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @HowardHinnant Removed my suggestion for using perfect forwarding here. I guess we'll have to use `enable_if` or constraints here to restrict T to what can be used to construct `vec`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant you may wanna go over https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645986/constructor-using-stdforward. Awfully good explanation imo.

Answer (score 0):

In your case there will be zero changes in performance as input in both cases is `const`

Generally, with correct usage of move constructors the gains would be big as there wouldn't be any unnecessay copying and allocations - one for each instance of `std::vector`.