# Having class inherit constructors of template type

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I created the following class to create values of any type which are either fixed or recalculated everytime the call operator is used on them:

```
template <typename T>
class DynamicValue {
    private:
    std::variant<T, std::function<T()>> getter;

    public:
    DynamicValue(const T& constant) : getter(constant){};
    template <typename F, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<F>>>
    DynamicValue(F&& function) : getter(function) {}
    DynamicValue(const T* pointer) : DynamicValue([pointer]() { return *pointer; }) {}
    DynamicValue(const DynamicValue& value) : getter(value.getter) {}
    ~DynamicValue() {}
    DynamicValue& operator=(const DynamicValue& value) {
        getter = value.getter;
        return *this;
    }
    T operator()() {
        return getter.index() == 0 ? std::get<T>(getter) : std::get<std::function<T()>>(getter)();
    }
};
```

I also wrote the following dummy struct to showcase my issue:

```
struct A {
    int b;
};
```

The problem is, ideally, I'd be able to initialize any `DynamicValue<T>` as if it were of type `T`. So, in this example, because I can do `A a = {1};`, instead of having to write `DynamicValue<A> a = A{1};`, I'd be able to do `DynamicValue<A> a = {1};`. However, when I attempt to do so, I get the folowing error:

> could not convert '{1}' from '' to 'DynamicValue'

You can try a live example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Y897s9).

Is there anyway to overcome this issue or must I accept the longer syntax?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645986/constructor-using-stdforward

Comment: `= {1}` is an initialization syntax for aggregates, which is not available for non-aggregate classes. Instead of that you should use unified initialization syntax `{1}`.

Comment: Braced initialization lists have no type and, as such, are quite difficult to work with in the context of templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a constructor which takes all parameters which a type `T` needs and forward them to the constructor of `T` and initialize your internal value `getter`.

Simply add the following lines to your class:

```
template < typename ... S> DynamicValue( S&& ... parms ): getter{T{ std::forward<S...>( parms... )}} {}
```

BUT! if we do this, it will also be invoked if we pass a non const DynamicValue. So we have to exclude it via SFINAE and get:

```
template <typename F,
   typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<F>&&    !std::is_same_v<std::remove_reference_t<F>, DynamicValue<T>>, bool>>
            DynamicValue(F&& function) : getter(function) {}
```

But there is another problem:

Your code already has something which can be invoked as a copy constructor which is not intended!

The constructor:

```
template <typename F, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<F>>>
    DynamicValue(F&& function) : getter(function) {}
```

will also be invoked, as `DynamicType<T>` is also invocable! We must also use the second condition to disable the instantiation of type `DynamicType<T>` which results in:

```
template <typename F, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<F>&& !std::is_same_v<std::remove_reference_t<F>, DynamicValue<T>>, bool>>
            DynamicValue(F&& function) : getter(function) {}
```

You are able to create an instance with:

```
DynamicValue<A> a1 = A{1};
DynamicValue<A> a2{1};
```

Using `= {1}` will not work.

And now even the fragment

```
DynamicValue<A> a9{100};
DynamicValue<A> a10(a9);
std::cout << a10().b << std::endl;
```

works as expected.

Comment: You definitely want to constrain this template.  Otherwise it will be used as the "copy constructor" for lvalues.

Comment: @NathanOliver: As now copy and move constructors are in place, the template will not be used for copy/move operation anymore. I am right?

Comment: If you do `DynamicValue<A> a;` and then `DynamicValue<A> a(b)`, your forwarding constructor will be called as it will exactly match the type of `a` where the copy constructor would preform a const conversion and the move constructor can't bind to lvalues.